# Prove a set is open using the definition a open set

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Prove using the definition, that the set $A$ defined by:
$$A=\{ (x,y)\in R^2 |y>M|x|, \text{ with } M>0, M \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
is a open set.

My solution:

Be $\overrightarrow{x}=(x,y)\in A$ a point in the set $A$.

So $y>M|x|$

Be $\epsilon=min\{ \frac{|Mx+y|}{\sqrt{(M)^2+1^2}} ,\frac{|-Mx+y|}{\sqrt{(-M)^2+1^2}} \}$.

is the min distance of point and lines $y=Mx, y=-Mx$

So be $B(\overrightarrow,\epsilon)$ a ball centered in $\overrightarrow{x}$ of radius $\epsilon$

Be $\overrightarrow{A}=(a,b)$ a point in $B(\overrightarrow{x},\epsilon)$

So here is the problem. i have to show that $b>M|a|$, but idk how show that

Comment: Side question (does not change your problem): do you mean $$A=\{ (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid\exists M\in\Bbb N, y>M|x|\}$$ or is $M$ fixed?

Comment: only that M>0, but can fixed, i think the set A its equals to set B=$\{ (x,y) \in R^2 | y>|x|\}$

Comment: If you only mean that $M\in\Bbb N$ (which implies $M>0$) but $M$ is not fixed, i.e. if your $A$ is what I wrote, then indeed $A=B$ hence you should simplify your post.

Comment: Hint: (with $M=1$) your $\epsilon=\frac1{\sqrt2}\min(y+x,y-x)$ (absolute values useless, both terms are $>0$) is the distance from $y$ to the complement of $A.$

Comment: Jmmm okay okay, i Will try !